# LinqDataSource Where Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linqdatasource

I have the below query on my aspx page that works:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="InventoryDataContext" 
    EntityTypeName="" TableName="V_InventoryForDisplays" 
    Where="ConfiguredCarId == @ConfiguredCarId">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2827" Name="ConfiguredCarId" Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I need to change the Where clause to use a Contains statement. I have an auto-propertyЖ

```
public IEnumerable<int> ConfiguredCarIds { get; set; }
```

within the same class that I would like to use

so what is the proper syntax to do this:

```
Where="ConfiguredCarIds.Contains (ConfiguredCarId)"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Where="ConfiguredCarId.Contains(@ConfiguredCarId)"`

Comment: I want to do the opposite Contains statement. Never mind, I gave up on the LinqDataSource and now uses an Object which does the underlying Linq query. I find the syntax easier

Comment: I hear you on that.  Just remember you also have the option of setting the selecting_event on the linqdatasource.