# Data filtering on gridview-want to show ALL records by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql

Here is my GridView  and LinqDataSource

```
<div id="container">

     <asp:GridView ID="dgvClients" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvClients_SelectedIndexChanged"
         CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" GridLines="None"
         ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceClient">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="accno" HeaderText="Acc No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="accno"></asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="clientname" HeaderText="Client name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="clientname"></asp:BoundField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch" SortExpression="t_branch.branch" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <%# Eval("t_branch.branch")%>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="active"></asp:BoundField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="lastupdated" HeaderText="Last Updated" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="lastupdated"></asp:BoundField>
         </Columns>
         <Columns>
         </Columns>
         <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />
     </asp:GridView>
     <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" EntityTypeName="" ID="LinqDataSourceClient" ContextTypeName="mcollector.mcollectorDataContext" OrderBy="accno, clientname, branchid" Select="new (accno, clientname, branchid, active, lastupdated, t_branch)" TableName="t_Clients" Where="accno == @accno">
         <WhereParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBoxSearch" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="" Name="accno" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
         </WhereParameters>
     </asp:LinqDataSource>
 </div>
```

i have a textbox , when it is empty i want to display all records from the table.
 How can i do that ?

Comment: add a default value to your ControlParameter. E.g. - DefaultValue="%"

Comment: i added but still not working @GuyNethery

Comment: You could try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894654/linqdatasource-where-parameter  Where="accno.Contains(@accno)".  Are you wanting an exact match on the Textbox or more a LIKE match?  Also, I see you added the DefaultValue but it has no value.  Don't you need to have "%" as the default value to match everything.

Comment: when i pass to the default value the sign" % ", i don't see any records, but by default i want to grid view to show all records.

Comment: I think Where="accno == @accno" is an exact match.  so "%" is an exact match to no records.  Change Where="accno == @accno" to Where="accno.Contains(@accno)" this is the equivalent to a LIKE statement as I under stand it.

Comment: i made the change: `      <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" EntityTypeName="" ID="LinqDataSourceClient" ContextTypeName="mcollector.mcollectorDataContext" OrderBy="accno, clientname, branchid" Select="new (accno, clientname, branchid, active, lastupdated, t_branch)" TableName="t_Clients" Where="accno.Contains(@accno)">
             <WhereParameters>
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBoxSearch" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%" Name="accno" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
             </WhereParameters>
         </asp:LinqDataSource>`

Comment: the default value does not show all the records, the accno.Contains() works as the like in the database. thank you for the tips. but why all the records don't show when i pass the % in the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You could code your logic in the  LinqDataSource.Selecting Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.selecting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i will try and let you know the result